# Will 100,000 probe requests per day impact network performance?

Tags: wireless-networking, network-traffic

Is it normal for Sonos devices to send ~100,000 probe requests per day? It is kind of flooding out my network analysis. I can just filter this traffic out, but before I do I wanted to find out if this is normal behavior.

I have a Sonos Play:3, Playbar and Connect. They are all connected via wifi, none of them are plugged in. Examining my network traffic, I see that they are constantly spamming probe requests to Sonos_RanDomStrInGoF4lPh4Num (I made that name up but that's the basic idea). I guess that is a mesh network that the three devices use?

I am wondering if the devices are somehow misconfigured and if this will impact the rest of my network.

Comment: If you downvote, please let me know what I can do to improve the question.

Comment: I don't have any Sonos, so can't test.  What exactly are the packets in question?  Did a bit if reading and evidently these things can make their own networks that are prone to creating Ethernet loops.  `Probes` are often broadcast/mulitcast frames that can do bad things when a loop is present.

Comment: They are 802.11 probe requests, broadcast to ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff.  I think it is so the Sonos devices can interact with the app on your phone.  I just wonder if this will impact network performance.  It looks like they will easily broadcast over 100,000 probe requests today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see. 100,000 packets per day, and one day is 86,400 seconds. That's less than 1.2 small packets per second. Let's say they're 200 Bytes (1,600 bits) each, and sent at the least efficient data rate of 1Mbps. That's a little more than 0.1% (one-tenth of one percent) of your airtime.

That's nothing.

In comparison, a typical idle AP sends 10 beacons per second, so roughly 10x this much airtime is wasted on beacons.

I can't speak as to whether this is the expected behavior of Sonos devices or not.